# Are there examples of laws/patterns that prevent "Manufactured Consent"

Tags: democracy, media

This is a rewrite of a more biased and now closed question I thought had a good core.

In the 1988 book Manufacturing Consent, Herman/Chomsky argued that corporate mass media have a symbiosis with the government that promote the governments point of views.

A simplified US example could be that media is not given a chance to ask questions at White House Press Briefings unless they have the point of view of the government.

Does any countries actively have laws or patterns that try to level the playingfield for medias access to government even if those media are opposed to the government, and has it successfully been implemented?

Does this symbiosis show e.g. in work by Transparency International and is it considered a problem in relations to democracy at large?

Edit/Addition: It could be a pattern like many parliaments, at least in Europe, have where all parties can ask government questions and they are not allowed to lie. (But just for media)

Comment: To clarify, when you talk about "media having the point of view of the government" you are not speaking in partisan terms.  Eg, Fox News does have access to White House Briefings, but are frequently critical of the current President.  You are talking about a hypothetical media organisation that is opposed to the very existence of the USA and the idea of a President as defined in the Constitution, eg the "[Daily Stormer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daily_Stormer)"

Comment: Government and press in a *symbiosis*? What evidence do Herman/Chomsky give for this outlandish claim? I mean, in biology, symbiosis means that species are codependent on each other to the point neither can survive alone. Why would the survival of the mass media depend upon being allowed to ask questions at press briefings?

Comment: This isn't exactly what was argued in the book. A more accurate distillation would be that government is the shadow cast by industry over society and that the mass media sells a rather privileged audience to corporate advertisers, which leads to the conclusion that the media relationship with the population at large should reflect the interests of the buyers, sellers and product. This is in fact what we see.

Comment: A better example would be that people do not even arrive at the position to ask questions of the rulers unless their attitudes already reflect those of the corporate media, their privileged audience and the wealthy advertisers. Perfect example right here. My attitudes do not reflect the interests of those who can punish me here so i am not allowed to ask or answer questions. Is this stack ostensibly a democracy? There is the veneer of participation but consensus of those in authority seems to rule while bystanders (the bulk of the population)  have no influence or control.

Comment: I realize this isn't the place for it, but since i have no other option I'll ask here. What exactly was this "bias" I'm being accused of? Are you conflating bias with minority view? It's worth bearing in mind that it's much easier to be wrong and conformist than it is to be correct and stand against consensus. Consequently there will always be more people who are wrong than people who are right. In inconsequential matters such as where is the nearest coffee shop the majority can be right. In important matters that require hard work and great talent, the majority is always wrong.

Comment: @meriton the constitution deals more with media than other topics, 1A for example. Politicians can't win if people don't know about them. Professional media can't write news without candidates and officials talking to them or at least in public. Election ad buys push many stations into the black. Free coverage elevates candidates who would otherwise be ignored.

Comment: @meriton From least controversial cases - Project Veritas published a few years ago a recording of some journalists, who was unhappy that she had neat material implicating a few people to on trips to Epstein pleasure island, while the station decided it's better business to stay silent (including loosing any chance for interview with British royal family), while ultimately others get the fame for making the stuff public.

Answer (score -5):

Here's a relatively well-known one:

**Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.**

In theory this protects the right of dissent but in practice it rarely protects free speech, instead greatly favoring paid speech. (Eg, *According to the Court, limits on campaign contributions and expenditures implicate rights of political expression and association under the First Amendment. The Court, however, afforded different degrees of First Amendment protection and levels of scrutiny to contributions and expenditures.*) [1](https://crsreports.congress.gov/product/pdf/LSB/LSB10734)

As far as mind control being a peculiar problem of democracies in general, Chomsky argues that the more free a country is the more it must rely on indoctrination, because without such indoctrination men would not have a tolerance for civil rule. He further argues that totalitarian states rely less on indoctrination because they have a big club to hit you over the head with. They aren't concerned with what you think, only what you do, and nobody ever thought their way out of bondage.

Comment: *..In theory this protects the right of dissent but in practice it rarely protects free speech, instead greatly favoring paid speech...* Your example does not demonstrate this claim in the slightest.

Comment: "They [totalitarian governments] aren't concerned with what you think, only what you do, and nobody ever thought their way out of bondage." earned my downvote. That statement is demonstrably false. Totalitarian governments are the most concerned over your thoughts than other governments. They have the most laws related to censorship and preventing one from easily sharing his thoughts. And in many cases, totalitarian gov's have been known to execute people based on their beliefs, regardless of their actions. Your answer needs to be somewhat truthful, even if you claim its a minority opinion.